# Implementing Spring Security Oauth without XML configuration

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to build a basic REST service that's secured with Spring Security, with OAuth 2.0 authentication and authorization.

I'm trying to limit the elements involved, so rather than copy-pasting a Spring Security Oath XML configuration relying on Spring Beans, Spring MVC, etc, I'm using the Spring Security Oauth classes directly.

I've hit a snag when trying to get an Access Token from /oauth/token. I'm probably missing something basic, but both Spring Security and Spring Security Oauth are hard to wrap my head around and I can't seem to find a single example or tutorial that doesn't require using extra frameworks.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

RestService.java

```
@Path("/members")
public class RestService {

    @Secured({"ROLE_USER"})
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response readMember(@PathParam("id") String id) {

        String output;
        if(Integer.valueOf(id) < members.size())
        {
            output = members.get(Integer.valueOf(id)).toString();
        }
        else
        {
            output = "No such member.";
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

OAuthServices.java

```
public class OAuthServices {

    static private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    static private InMemoryClientDetailsService clientDetailsService = new InMemoryClientDetailsService();

    static {
        Map<String, ClientDetails> clientDetailsStore = new HashMap<String, ClientDetails>();
        BaseClientDetails clientDetails = new BaseClientDetails("client", "resource", null, null, "read,write");
        clientDetailsStore.put("client", clientDetails);
        clientDetailsService.setClientDetailsStore(clientDetailsStore);
    }

    public static DefaultTokenServices getTokenServices() {
        return tokenServices;
    }

    public static InMemoryClientDetailsService getClientDetailsService() {
        return clientDetailsService;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                    .and()
                    .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
                <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.excentus.springsecurity.rest.test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to expect people to review. I suggest stating your problem more succinctly if possible.

Comment: I was thinking it would be useful to have it there to reference if necessary, although most of it shouldn't be relevant. I can cut it down though if that's frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 errors (maybe not the whole story).

1. You are using `web.xml` but there is no Spring Security filter defined there. It's boiler plate code but you have to do it (unless you switch to a more modern way of writing your app with Spring Boot for instance). Example (from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml)):

   springSecurityFilterChain
     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

   springSecurityFilterChain
     /*
2. You have implemented `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` but not implemented any of its methods. At a minimum you need to provide client details, e.g. (from [integration tests(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/vanilla/src/main/java/demo/Application.java)):

   ```
       @Override
   public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
       clients.inMemory()
           .withClient("my-trusted-client")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
               .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
               .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
               .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
               .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60);
   }
   ```

Your static convenience class `OAuthServices` is also kind of an anti pattern, but it won't break anything (I don't see it being used anywhere either, but maybe missed that).